# Looping API call multiple times getting random results

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, api

I'm calling the following API/Json Object and trying to display each value three times in three separate columns. I get the all three columns but in each one I get way more results then I truly want.

example: col 1 shows me all 9 results col 2 shows me 6 results and col 3 shows me 3

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var api_url = 'private_API Here';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: api_url ,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
            for (const prop in result.rates) {
                $(".row").append("<div class='column'>");

                for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){ 
                let para = document.createElement("p"); 
                para.innerHTML = `${result.rates[prop].toFixed(3)} ${prop} `; 
                 }

                $( ".column" ).append( para );
                // document.getElementById("content").appendChild(para);

                // console.log(`Country: ${prop}, currency rate: ${result.rates[prop].toFixed(2)}`);
                $(".row").append("</div>");
              }
        }

  })
});
```

here is the API/object that I am calling.

```
{
"rates": {
  "EEE": 0.9061254078,
  "RRR": 9.8219463574,
  "GGG": 0.8206324755
 }
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>API CAll</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
 * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }

div p{
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
}
.row {
    display: flex;
}

.column {
    flex: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}
</style>
<body>

<div id="content" class="row">

</div>
</body>
 </html>
```

if there is anything details that I am missing please let me know.

Comment: Provide the result json you are getting . And html code if possible .

Comment: sorry I forgot the HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add `<div class='column'>` elements to the document.  Then, each time through the outer loop, you then run `$( ".column" ).append( para );` which matches the column you just added, *as well as all prior columns you've added.*

Instead, create the `<div>` and store its jQuery object, then add elements to it.

There's also something fishy going on with `para`; you declare it with `let` but then use it outside of the block it's declared in. You can't do that with `let`.  (In `$( ".column" ).append( para );`, the `para` variable should be undefined as it has gone out of scope.)

Also, you only append the *last* version of this element.

Based on the above two observations, I'm speculating that the behavior you've observed was from a different iteration of your code than the one you've showed us.

Regardless, here is the fixed code with comments showing what was changed:

```
// Create the column and store its jQuery object to use later.
let column = $("<div class='column'></div>");

// TODO: Should you match .row here, or use a specific row?
$(".row").append(column);

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // Use jQuery to create the P element instead of the DOM.
    let para = $('<p></p>');
    // Use the jQuery text() method to set the content.  (Prevents element
    // injection by server via innerHTML.)
    para.text(`${result.rates[prop].toFixed(3)} ${prop} `);

    // Append this element only to the one div we created this iteration of the
    // outer loop.
    column.append(para);
}
```

I also removed `$(".row").append("</div>");` -- "partial elements" can't exist in the DOM, so adding the end tag *after* you've already created the element is nonsense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it worked perfectly! But when I tried this in IE and nothing shows up, would you have an idea why that would be?

Comment: @whisk I would need to see a complete example of the code that's breaking on IE. Basically, something I can just open in IE and have it run, not small snippets.

Comment: I started another question about this [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778150/ie-11-not-displaying-anything-at-all/57778292?noredirect=1#comment101991985_57778292) but really there isn't much more code.

Comment: @whisk Hah, right, I forgot IE11 doesn't support ES6. The person who answered there is correct.

Comment: so when I run it locally nothing still shows. Would you know of a setting i could change?  I set everything back to default for IE. If not no worries.

Comment: @whisk I'd need to see the updated ES5 code that doesn't work.