# IE 11 Not displaying anything at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-11

The following code is working in all browser but EI11. There are no errors in the console or displayed anywhere. I have been on `Stack Overflow` for the last two day trying all of the other answered questions, anything from  cache breaking, adding header option. At a lost here, any guidance would be grateful and i'll add any additional info ass needed.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>API CAll</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div p{
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
}
.row {
    display: flex;
}

.column {
    flex: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

   <div id="content" class="row"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**JS**

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {

  var api_url2 = 'https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD&symbols=TRY,BRL,MXN';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: api_url2 ,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){

        const objVal = result.rates;             
        var keys = [], k, i, len;

        for (k in objVal) {
            if (objVal.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                keys.push(k);
            }
        }

        keys.sort();

          len = keys.length;

          for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            k = keys[i];
            console.log(k + ':' + objVal[k]);
            let column = $("<div class='column'></div>");

                for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                // TODO: Should you match .row here, or use a specific row?
                $(".row").append(column);
                // Use jQuery to create the P element instead of the DOM.
                let para = $('<p></p>');
                // Use the jQuery text() method to set the content.  (Prevents element
                // injection by server via innerHTML.)
                para.text(`${objVal[k].toFixed(3)} ${k} `);

                // Append this element only to the one div we created this iteration of the
                // outer loop.
                column.append(para);
                }
          }


        }
  })
 });
```

Comment: What does "not displaying correctly" mean?

Comment: when I refresh the page nothing is displayed.

Comment: `const` and `let` aren't completely supported in IE11. Maybe avoid those if you're not transpiling your source. https://caniuse.com/#search=const

Answer (score 2):

IE11 doesn't support ES6. That means, you need to replace:

- Template literals with old ES5 syntax `'string' + 'string'`
- let/const with `var` (as @lostero mentioned, let/const are supported in IE11, [but not fully](https://caniuse.com/#search=let)), so it is better to avoid them.

or use ES6+ > ES5 transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)

Anyway, here is code for IE:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  var api_url2 = 'https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD&symbols=TRY,BRL,MXN';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: api_url2 ,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){

        const objVal = result.rates;             
        var keys = [], k, i, len;

        for (k in objVal) {
            if (objVal.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                keys.push(k);
            }
        }

        keys.sort();

          len = keys.length;

          for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            k = keys[i];
            console.log(k + ':' + objVal[k]);
            var column = $("<div class='column'></div>");

                for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                // TODO: Should you match .row here, or use a specific row?
                $(".row").append(column);
                // Use jQuery to create the P element instead of the DOM.
                var para = $('<p></p>');
                // Use the jQuery text() method to set the content.  (Prevents element
                // injection by server via innerHTML.)
                para.text(objVal[k].toFixed(3) + k );

                // Append this element only to the one div we created this iteration of the
                // outer loop.
                column.append(para);
                }
          }


        }
  })
 });
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div p{
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
}
.row {
    display: flex;
}

.column {
    flex: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="content" class="row"></div>
```

[Live code](https://jsfiddle.net/1sh9akfd/)

Comment: I see you have `version 3.3.1` and I'm using `version jquery-3.4.1`, is that going to be a key factor here?

Comment: @whisk not really, you can use newest version.

Comment: I'm trying your changes and nothing is still showing up. Is there some settings in IE that might cause this?

Comment: @whisk well, it works for me, try to open [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/1sh9akfd/embedded/result,css,html,js) in IE11. Is it working?